# How do I access "assigns" after "render :template => ..."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have an error handling method in my ApplicationController:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

def not_found(exception)
  @exception = exception
  render :template => '/errors/not_found', :status => 404
end
```

In `RAILS_ROOT/app/views/errors/not_found.html.erb`, I have this:

```
<h1>Error 404: Not Found</h1>
<%= debug @exception %>
```

But `@exception` is always `nil` there.  I've tried `debug assigns`, but that's always `{}`.  Do assigns not get copied when calling `render :template`?  If so, how can I get them?

I'm on edge Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's odd, and I don't know why.  As an alternative, have you tried passing the exception as an explicit local?

```
def not_found(exception)
  render :template => '/errors/not_found', 
         :status   => 404, 
         :locals   => {:exception => exception}
end
```

and the view:

```
<h1>Error 404: Not Found</h1>
<%= debug exception %> <!-- Note no '@' -->
```

Comment: oh, wait!  yes!  without the @!

Answer (score 1):

From the API documentation for [ActionController::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000848) it looks like you should try:

```
render :template => '/errors/not_found', :status => 404, :locals => {:exception => exception}
```